# Guess a number program with c

Tags: c

I need to write a program that plays the game "guess the number" when the computer selects the number from 1 to 100, and the user has 10 attempts, each round the user receives output if the number he guessed is too small or too big, or if its the lucky number your help please

thats what i did so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {


    int i ,guess=0 , lucky=rand()%100;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        printf("please enter your guess\n");
        scanf("%d",&guess);



        }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you got?

Comment: A google check might reveal something like this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24366/guess-the-number-game-in-c amongst many other resources.

Comment: Just look at the *related* side bar on the right of your screen.  This question has been asked a bajillion times before.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int count , guess = 0, lucky = rand() % 101;


    for (count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
        printf("please enter your guess\n>");
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        if(guess == lucky) {
            printf("WIN");
            break;
        }

        if(guess > lucky)
            printf("too big\n\n");
        else
            printf("too small\n\n");

    }

    if(count == 10)
        printf("FAIL");


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `lucky` will have a value 0 to 100, not `1 to 100`.

Comment: @oggy Your welcome! Have a nice day! (BTW: You can accept and upvote an answer how helped you so that people with the same problem find the answer faster!) If you want lucky to be 1 -> 100 then use `rand() % 100 +1`